# When two clients connected to same room. Is a message from one client to the room, go to the another clients?

Tags: socket.io

Until now, I only send messages in `socket.io` from client to server, or from a server to client.

Now I want to send some messages between `client1`, to `client2`.  One of the clients will emit the messages, the another client will listen.

My question is if it is gonna work?

**client1:**

```
io.join('myroom')
```

**client2:**

```
io.to('myroom').emit('mymessage',)
```

Is `client1` will get the message from client2?

---

**In another word:**  Is socket.io server, also moving messages between clients, or only emit client from itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do `io.join()` from the client.  That is only something a server can do.

So, you need to use the server to `.join()` clients into rooms.  You can create your own message that the client sends to the server requesting to be added to a room and have the server do it for you.

You also can't send a message directly to a room from a client with `io.to('myroom').emit('mymessage')`.  That is functionality only available on the server.  You can only send from a client to the server.  So, again, you would create your own message that the client sends to the server that asks the server to broadcast this message to a specific room.

So, from a client, you could do something like this:

```
io.send("requestJoin", "myroom");
```

And, later you could ask the server to send to that room like this:

```
io.send("sendToRoom", {room: "myroom", msg: "Hello"});
```

The server could then have handlers for these two messages:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on("requestJoin", function(room) {
        socket.join(room);
    });

    socket.on("requestLeave", function(room) {
        socket.leave(room);
    });

    socket.on("sendToRoom", function(data) {
        io.to(data.room, data.msg);
    });
});
```

It is implemented this way for a couple reasons:

1. Clients only have a connection to the server, not to other clients so anything that you want sent to another client has to be sent to the server.
2. Servers have control over what client can join what room.  So, if you want a client to join a room, you have to ask the server to do it and the server gets to decide if it wants to actually do that on your behalf.
3. Rooms are entirely a server concept and data structure so it's entirely up to the server to manage them.

Comment: Another question: When 2 servers connected to same socket redis adapter. Is both of them get messages from the client same time?

Comment: @Aminadav - This sounds like a new and different question concerning how the redis adapter works with multiple servers.  I'd suggest you describe your situation in detail in a new question.

Comment: The question: [When 2 servers connected to same socket redis adapter. Is both of them get messages from the client same time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38820666/when-2-servers-connected-to-same-socket-redis-adapter-is-both-of-them-get-messa)