# When 2 servers connected to same socket redis adapter. Is both of them get messages from the client same time?

Tags: socket.io

I have two servers `server-a` and `server-b`.

For using `socket.io` usually, the two servers are using redis adapter. Then the client can connect  to `server-a` or `server-b`.

Now the question is: If the client is connected to `server-a` and emit a message. Is `server-b` have an option to get the message?

The client code:

```
io.emit('sendMessage',myMessage)
```

The Server-a Code:

```
io.on('sendMessage',function(){
     console.log('Server A got the message')
}
```

The Server-a Code:

```
io.on('sendMessage',function(){
     console.log('Server B got the message')
}
```

The `client` is connected only to `server-a`. `server-a` & `server-b` are using the same redis adapter.

**The question is:** When client emit a message, is `server-b` will get it? (`Server-B` is only connected to the same redis)

**What I want to do:** I have several servers that should do an action, based on client request. When client request something, all the servers needs to start works. I thought to do with `socket.io`, and to keep one connection between the client and on of the servers.

All the servers will use `socket.io` to get the same message from the client.

Comment: You'd have to show us exactly how you're sending the message (please show actual code) and how you have setup the socket.io redis adapter.

Comment: I have added some details. Let me know if anything unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the redis adapter properly with all your servers, then when you do something like:

```
io.emit('sendMessage',myMessage)
```

from any one of your servers, then that message will end up being sent to all the clients connected to all your servers.  What happens internally is the message is sent to a redis channel which all the servers are listening to.  When each server gets the message, they then broadcast to all their users but these last steps are transparently handled for you by the redis adapter and redis store.

So, `io.emit()` is used to send to all connected clients (which uses all the servers in order to carry out the broadcast).  It is not used to broadcast the same message directly to all your servers so that they can each manually process that message.

To send to each of your servers, you could probably use your own custom redis publish/subscribe channel messages since each server is already connected to redis and this is something that redis is good at.

Or, you could designate one master socket.io server and have all the other servers connect to it with socket.io.  Then any server could ask the central server to broadcast a message to all the other servers.

Comment: Thank you. The question is if there is a way to broadcast a message to all the servers?

If no, my solution is, to make all the server behave like a clients, and connect to the main server.

Comment: @Aminadav - See the newly added last two paragraphs.

Comment: Thank. Just a question, when you do `@Aminadav`, is stackoverflow server, do something with it? Send me a notification?
I

Comment: @Aminadav - Yes, stackoverflow will notify you of my comment.  There are some cases where you will automatically be notified anyway because of the context, but this makes sure that your comment is seen by one particular other user.